# Guzzle get request

Tags: php, guzzle

I am trying to figure out how to download a file from a form that's on a website that requires login.

I can login with no issues using POST and the below code:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

 $response = $client->post('http://websitename.com/account/login.php', array(
         'body' => array(
             'username' => '######',
             'password' => '######'
         ),
         'cookies' => true
     )
 );
```

the `$response` leads me past the login page successfully.

But if I attempt to make a `GET` call after the fact using `$client->get` it leads me back to the login page.

How can I `POST` my login information and then go to another page `exportdata.php` to then `GET` form information from it?

Answer (score 0):

I had some trouble using the `cookies => true` option. have you tried providing a default `CooieJar`?

Example:

```
$jar = new GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJar();
$default = [
    "cookies" => $jar
];
$c = new GuzzleHttp\Client(["defaults" => $default]);
```

The same cookie jar is now set by default to each request made by that client.